# Create list of lists starting from an ordered list

Tags: java, list

I need to populate a datatable with a series of records taken from a db.

The records are already ordered by 4 fields (sig, sup, nOda and odaPos) but I need to create a list of lists that has sig and sup as key and the rest of the fields as values.

In this way I can avoid giving the datatable the job of grouping and ordering the results...

Any help?

Comment: definetely get a hunch on HashMap<>. its what u are looking for i guess

Answer (score 0):

You could create two new classes. Key for sig and sup. Value für noda, odapos.
And then store them in a Map.

```
public class Key{
Object sig;
Object sup; 
} 
public class Value{
Object noda;
Object odaPos;
}
public Map<Key,Value> map = new HashMap<>();
```